# problem in recognition of numbers in system.speech?

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, sapi

speech and i added grmmar which only detects numbers like this

```
            SpeechRecognitionEngine RecognitionEngine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new CultureInfo("en-US", true));

            // Created Grammar For only Numbers 1 to 10
            var NumberChoice = new Choices();
            for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                NumberChoice.Add(i.ToString());
            }
            var NumGrammarBuilder = new GrammarBuilder(NumberChoice);
            var NumGrammar = new Grammar(NumGrammarBuilder);
            RecognitionEngine.LoadGrammar(NumGrammar);

            RecognitionEngine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
            RecognitionResult Result = RecognitionEngine.Recognize();

            txt_vtc.Text = Result.Text;
```

But when i speak the outputs are getting different some times, when i say two it gets eight and the most worse thing is when i switch on my fan and speak , its not recognizing even for small sound. so is this is usefull for normal client? When the client says pin, it has to capture the pin code and save it in text file.. is this is usefull for me..

its more than enough if it recognizes from 1 to 10 correctly for me? Can anybody help me in this scenario.
can i show progress bar or any meter when the user speaks?
can i use ENglish - UK Culture to my speech recognition?
Do we have any third party dlls for this?

Regards
Bhuvan

Comment: Speech recognition fails in noisy environments. Reduce noise or fail.

Comment: ok.. i assume that i reduced noisy... will it display the numbers corretly? How about the progress bar when the user speaks? is this possible to implement progress bar?

Comment: What kind of progress bar did you have in mind?

Comment: progressbar in the sense.. i just need an audio meter when the user speaks which i see in sound recorder

Answer (score 2):

you can try this code sample in order to overcome your problem

```
  SpeechRecognitionEngine rec = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
  var c = new Choices();
  for (var i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
      c.Add(i.ToString());
  var gb = new GrammarBuilder(c);
  var g = new Grammar(gb);
  g.Priority = 127;
  rec.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();

  rec.LoadGrammar(g);
  rec.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
```

Comment: Nice and simple. Why do you set the priority on the grammar? Does it do anything if you only have one grammar loaded in the engine?

Comment: Please play with this feature and let us all know in another comment.I wrote this solution a long time a go and I don't really remember...